# How to use dynamicToolbarColor() in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Following code getting only one image from resource, How to change this to dynamic images, I'm getting images as bitmap.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.pfpic);

    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary));
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Converting only  one image, You mentioned that you are getting images in the form of bitmaps right?!, Why don't you use that bitmap reference?!.

```
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);            
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

You can use 'bmp' in following code like this

```
    Palette.from(bmp).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, Works fine like piece of cake, Thank you so much Mr.Harish Reddy.